# Is it possible to not-install docs with ExeUtils::MakeMaker?

Tags: docker, perl, makefile, manpage, build-system

I'm looking into setting up Perl micro services with Docker and Alpine. Alpine's convention is not be weighed down by docs/man pages by default.

If my `Makefile.PL` uses [`ExeUtils::MakeMaker`](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::MakeMaker) is there a way to not-install docs?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the targets available

```
perl Makefile.PL
grep -i phony ./Makefile
```

They are

> `all config static dynamic test linkext manifest blibdirs clean realclean disttest distdir pure_all subdirs clean_subdirs makemakerdflt manifypods realclean_subdirs subdirs_dynamic subdirs_pure_nolink subdirs_static subdirs-test_dynamic subdirs-test_static test_dynamic test_static`

It seems all of those options pertianing to install call `manifypods` and install the POD files.

I think the best you can do is to remove the pod files afterwards and purge the man pages. I did that by adding something like this to my Docker's `RUN` line to comprehensively clean up,

```
&& cpanm --installdeps .
&& perl Makefile.PL
&& make
&& make install
&& make distclean
&& rm -rfv ~/.cpanm /usr/local/share/man \
&& find /usr/share/perl5/ -name '*.pod' -delete
```

Comment: Related: [Where does CPAN install modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46778215/589924).  I wonder what happens if you specify an empty string for a directory (e.g. by passing `INSTALLMAN1DIR= INSTALLMAN3DIR= ` to `Makefile.PL`)