# Install perlcritic on macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, perl, zsh, cpan

I'm on macOS Ventura 13.3.1 and I'm trying to get `perlcritic` working.

```bash
perl --version
```

Gives me:

```
This is perl 5, version 36, subversion 0 (v5.36.0) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level

...
```

When I type:

```bash
cpan Perl::Critic
```

I get:

```bash
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
Reading '/Users/baduker/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sun, 07 May 2023 10:41:02 GMT
Perl::Critic is up to date (1.150).
```

However, when I try:

```bash
perlcritic -1 list.pl
```

I get:

```bash
zsh: command not found: perlcritic
```

I've also tried using `brew`

```
brew install perlcritic
```

But `brew` can't find it and suggests `perltidy`:

```bash
Warning: No available formula with the name "perlcritic". Did you mean perltidy?
==> Searching for similarly named formulae and casks...
==> Formulae
perltidy

To install perltidy, run:
  brew install perltidy
```

Additional debugging info:

```bash
which perl
/opt/homebrew/bin/perl
```

Running `perl -V:installsitebin` gives:

```
installsitebin='/opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.36.0/bin';
```

---

**Question:** How do I get `perlcirtic` working on macOS?

---

PS. `list.pl` looks like this:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Tiny;
use autodie;

my $dir = path("/tmp"); # /tmp

my $file = $dir->child("test");

my $content = $file->slurp_utf8();

my $file_handle = $file->openr_utf8();

while( my $line = $file_handle->getline() ) {
    print $line;
}
```

Comment: I suspect that `perlcritic` is installed but the path is not added to your `PATH` environment variable. Are you using the system perl? What is the output of `which perl` ?

Comment: `perlcritic` was most likely installed in `installsitebin` if you installed the module `Perl::Critic` with `cpan`. What is the output of running `perl -V:installsitebin` ? Check if that directory is in your `PATH` environment variable

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/46778964/2173773

Comment: @HåkonHægland, spot on, `perlcritic` was installed but not added to PATH. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Great that you found a solution! Are you using homebrew perl? Then this could be a bug in the homebrew setup?

Comment: Yes, I tend to use `brew` for all my local software needs; it's just easier that way. I'll try reinstalling perl and see if this happens again. If it does, then you might be right again. :)

Comment: *"Then this could be a bug in the homebrew setup?"* Added a related question on homebrew github page: https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/4489 to get more feedback on this issue

Comment: Nice one, @HåkonHægland! I'm following the issue. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the feedback in the comments, the fix is easy.

Run:

```bash
perl -V:installsitebin
```

To confirm the installation.

In my case, `perlciritic` gets installed, but, for some reason, `opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.36.0/bin` doesn't get added to `PATH`.

**Note**: I use `brew` `perl` installation.

The fix:

```bash
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.36.0/bin/
```

Then, running `perlcritic -1 list.pl` produces, for example:

```bash
No package-scoped "$VERSION" variable found at line 0, column 0.  See page 404 of PBP.  (Severity: 2)
```